# While deploying a contract transaction is not happening

Tags: transactions, mist, contract-deployment

I am a newbie in Both Solidity and Programming. 
I want to deploy a contract in MIST test network with some ethar. whan i pressing the publish button following error is showing.

i have added the following payable function...

```
function payTestFunds() payable{
    //do nothing function
}
```

my intention is to give some ethar to my contract account so that it can process some further transaction by itself.

```
function payRentToCarRentalServiceProvider(address _providerAddress) returns (bool){

    bool payStatus = true;
    if(_providerAddress.send(rentCar[_providerAddress].rent))
    {
        rentCar[_providerAddress].rent = 0;
        return payStatus;
    }
    else{
        return !payStatus;
    }
}
```

kindly help me...Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to send Ether during contract creation your function must be payable. If you are creating a new contract, making the function "payTestFunds()" payable is probably not enough, since the constructor is being called, not this method. Is your constructor also payable?
For simplicity, start by deploying the contract without any initial Ether. Then send Ether once the contract is created.

Also, why are you declaring a variable that is only ever true and never changes? Just do

```
if (...) {
  return true; 
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Agree with Max. To send ETH to the constructor, the constructor would have to be payable.  Send nothing while you deploy the contract and then send a transaction to new payTestFunds() function after the contract is deployed. It's a 2-step.

Comment: how can i make my constractor payable???i have tried tosome rther  send after deploying but not worked :-(

Comment: it works properly i have made my contractor also payable, simple write the payable keyword after the constractor name. Thanks a lot for your help